# How to find my android device ID to use with php notification script using Firebase?

Tags: php, firebase, push-notification

I'm trying to use a script i found on SO, it's a `php` script that pushes notifications using `Firebase`, in my app i'm trying to push notification to my Android device but i don't know how to identify my device's ID/Key, the script is the following:

```
$server_key=""; // get this from Firebase project settings->Cloud Messaging
$user_token=""; // Token generated from Android device after setting up firebase
$title="New Message";
$n_msg="The is a message";

$ndata = array('title'=>$title,'body'=>$n_msg);

$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

$fields = array();
$fields['data'] = $ndata;

$fields['to'] = $user_token;
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
  'Authorization:key='.$server_key
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

I'm trying  to identify the `$user_token` so i can use this script to serve my purpose.

Comment: Mobile app have to register with Firebase, then it will receive a Firebase token which is unique from each device. Use that token to send to your android device app.

Comment: I'm using my google account on phone for Firebase and i can't find where to get my Firebase token @catcon

Comment: Firebase is a separate service from your google account, also the your mobile app must support push notification. Please read Firebase documentation to understand how it work.

Comment: @catcon what i understand from your words is that Firebase only pushes notifications to an app you've made on android right? it can't push notifications to a device sort of like an SMS text message.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Firebase is for MOBILE APP PUSH NOTIFICATION. It send notification to a your app on a specific device. You can't just send any notification to any app or any device. For the service like you describe, Im not aware of any service have that capability besides SMS.

Comment: @catcon Sounds like an aswer! :)
Amine: You can't target a device with Firebase Cloud Messaging, as that would attract even more notification spam that users are already getting today. You can only target a specific app instance on a specific device. See here for full documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/